# How do I display Correlation matrix as percentage

Tags: r, correlation, ggcorrplot

I am trying to display the correlation labels as a percentage instead of displaying them between the numbers -1 and 1. I was able to do this using the package `ggcorrplot`, However doing this took away the capability of displaying them with the color pallet and display it with just a grey cell colors. This is how it looks like

[image]

I was able to do this using the package `ggcorrplot`, However doing this took away the capability of displaying them with the color pallet.

```
#if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
#devtools::install_github("kassambara/ggcorrplot")
library(ggcorrplot)
corr <- round(cor(test3),3)
corr <- corr * 100
ggcorrplot(corr, hc.order = TRUE, type = "lower",
           lab = TRUE, colors = c("blue", "white", "red"))
```

Is there way to get the results as a percentage and still have the colors as we normally have in a correlation matrix plot. Also any way to add percentage to the labels as currently it only displays the number.

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: Why do you want a percentage? The correlation coefficient is not a proportion, so just multiplying by 100 does not make sense. A value of zero, for example, does not mean 0%.

Comment: @neilfws If I have a correlation between two variables as 0.5, would that not  mean that they are 50% correlated

Comment: No, that it not what it means. In one sense, the number is a measure of how close the variables are to a straight line when plotted against each other. See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) for discussion and interpretations.

Comment: @d.b. That's what I am trying to explain here as to how much variation can be explained between the two variables. Now a number between `-1 to 1` would not make sense to general public, thus I was thinking if I can convert that to percentage and may be we in a sense can infer the same information

Comment: Percentage variation relates to the r-squared value in least squares regression. It's a measure of how close on average the x, y points are to a perfect linear fit. So it's related to correlation, but is a different value. It is **not** correct to express Pearson coefficients as a percentage.

Comment: @neilfws is correct. If nothing, you should do `corr = round(cor(test3)^2,3)`.

Comment: @d.b., Could you please explain how to interpret what you suggested above.

Comment: @AnalyticsTeam, `cor` (by default) gives you Pearson correlation coefficient (`r`). If you square that, you get `R²`

Comment: @d.b. thanks a lot for all the help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
corr <- round(cor(mtcars)^2,3)
corr <- corr * 100

diag(corr) = NA
corr[upper.tri(corr)] = NA

library(reshape2)
d = melt(corr)
d = d[!is.na(d$value),]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = Var1,
              y = Var2,
              fill = value,
              label = ifelse(is.na(value), "", paste0(value,"%")))) +
    geom_tile(color = "white") +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("green", "white", "red"), na.value = NA) +
    geom_text() +
    theme_bw()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Is there a way I can paste`%` in the value column of d

Comment: Thanks a lot that for the response, worked like magic. This is exactly what I was looking for